# simple program without using "if condition"?

Tags: if-statement, logic, logical-operators

Is there any way of creating a simple java(or c,c ++, python) program that prints 3 (outputs the 3) when given input=6 and it gives output=6 when given input=3 without using "if conditions" ?

Comment: Use a switch instead of if maybe? Why not using if tho? (Or ternary operator if only two possibilities).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're happy for it to produce other outputs on inputs that aren't 6 or 3, then you can just compute 9-x.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just use a switch-case statement. Also, if you only want those two answers, you could also take the input as an int and do 9-[your int] and print that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XOR bit operation. It compares pairs of bits and returns 0 if bits are equals and 1 if bits are different.
We have `3 = 011b` and `6 = 110b`. This numbers differ by 1 and 3 digit (bit), so XOR mask will be `101b = 5`.
Code example:

```
public static int testMethod(int value){
    return System.out.println(value ^ 5);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

without if or without control flow statement/condition statement ?
you could use switch statement

```
private void tes(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        ///give output 6 where input is 3
        case 3:
            System.out.println(6);
            break;
        ///give output 3 where input is 6
        case 6:
            System.out.println(3);
            break;
    }
}
```